# Help to identify larva found in sink?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I need some help in identifying this critter. It was found in southeast Georgia in a home I am renovating. There were several around the sink and toilet bowl.

Approximately 5 millimeters long. Stripes black/dark gray. Tapered end seems to be moving as though it was the head. Bulbous end has two extrusions like antennae?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found it!

Seems to actually be the pupae phase of the common drain fly - psychoda spp.

Looks like I'm going to be routing or replacing the pipes in that house.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please edit your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 